# What creatures can apparate?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-creatures, apparition

It's known that [House elves can apparate without a wand](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/161445/51085). Wizards can do it but [usually with a wand](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/149160/51085). Are there any other creatures able to apparate?

Comment: assuming you are meaning creatures that can initiate apparition on their own, rather than being a 'passenger' in side-along-apparition?

Comment: Well, I imagine a gorilla could be trained to operate a boat and rob ships on the high seas.... oh, wait, I thought you said ape-pirate.

Comment: The question you linked to seems to conclude that a wizard **doesn't** need a wand to apparate.

Comment: @Nit Thanks, I fixed it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Phoenixes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/17096/4918) and [Diricawls](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/131990/4918) can vanish and reappear at will, which may or may not count as Apparition.  Both of these are mentioned in the *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* book.  Professor Dumbledore's Phoenix Fawkes is even [shown to vanish together](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/17096/4918) with the Professor in *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*.  I don't have the book at hand, but I don't think any other creature is mentioned with similar abilities.

Comment: Poltergeists seems also to be able to apparate. In book 6 Peeves appears out of nothing while Dobby fights against Kreacher in the hospital wing.

Comment: @Lucharx I don't think so.  I suspect Peeves just floats through the walls of the castle, which is how he can arrive unexpectedly.

Comment: Yes I also think Peeves can float through walls like a normal ghost. But in this scene he appeared in the air with a loud bang same as the houselves before him. When there is a loud bang and someone appears out of nowhere it is mostly becauae of apparation. I can't quote the book because I only own the german version.